# HTML input default chrome border-color override with CSS not working

Tags: html, css

It works good only when i use full border declaration.
not working:

```
border-color: red;
```

working:

```
border: 1px solid red;
```

code example:

```css
/* Styles go here */

.example1 {
  border-color: red; /* not good */
}

.example2 {
  border: 1px solid red; /* works well */
}
```

```html
 <input class="example1">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input class="example2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `border-color` in this way, you would need to set the width and style:

```
border-color: red;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px;
```

Alternatively, you can set `border: 1px solid blue;` and then after that, override just the color using `border-color: red;`. This works, but only because the wodth and style have already been set.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't give other border properties, Styles from user agent stylesheet of browsers will get applied to the element.

here in your first example, if you inspect it in developer tool, it will show you `border-style:inset` inherited.

Answer (score 1):

When you're writing `border:` it's a shorthand property for all of the border styles. So when you write `border: 1px solid red` it becomes:

```css
.example2 {
  border: 1px solid red;/* Becomes: */
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}
```

However, when you just specify the colour, the browser has no idea what other styles the input should have, so it uses the default ones.

```css
.example1 {
  border-width: /* Uses default */
  border-style: /* Uses default */
  border-color: red;
}
```

There are a couple of ways to make it easier for you to customise the input boxes. You can select all input types and make them have a general border but then specify using classes more specific styles.

```css
input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input.red-border {
  border-color: red;
}

input.blue-border {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="red-border" value="I am Red"></input>
<input type="text" class="blue-border" value="I am Blue"></input>
```

However, I'm not sure that this answered your question since it seems as though both inputs have a red border. Try to format your questions better with some examples of what you want to achieve with more detail.

Hope this helps!